# What is std::expected in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling, c++-faq, c++23, std-expected

In one of the most respected stackoverflow answer I found an example of `std::expected` template class usages:
[What are coroutines in C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503656/what-are-coroutines-in-c20/44244451#44244451)

At the same time I cannot find any mentioning of this class on cppreference.com. Could you please explain what it is?

Comment: It's a fantasy - may not happen - but .. may still

Comment: you can't find it on cppreference because it is not a part of the standard

Comment: Some info about it: https://github.com/eugnsp/library/blob/master/cpp/std_library.md#stdexpected

Comment: It's still only a proposal https://wg21.link/p0323 - respected answer or not, everybody injects their opinions into answers, whether explicitly or implicitly. In this case, it was the opinion that `std::expected` should (and would) be standardized soon.

Comment: Like others had mentioned, `expected` was only proposed. But there are some user written ones you can lookup: https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected

Answer (score 63, accepted):

<sub>Actually, the best way to learn about `std::expected` is a funny talk by the (in)famous Andrei Alexandrescu: ["Expect the Expected!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH4WBuE1BHI)</sub>

#### What `std::expected` is, and when it's used

Here are three complementing explanations of what an `std::expected<T, E>` is:

- It  is the return type of a function which is supposed to return a `T` value - but which may encounter some error, in which case it will return a descriptor of that error, of type `E`.

  An example:

  ```c++
  std::expected<ParsedData, ParsingError> parse_input(Input input);
  ```
- It's an error-handling mechanism, being an alternative to throwing exceptions (in which case you always return the value you were supposed to), and to returning status/error codes (in which case you never return the value you want to, and have to use an out-parameter).

  Here are the two alternative error-handling mechanisms applied to the function from the previous example:

  ```c++
  ParsedData    parse_input_2(Input input) noexcept(false);
  ParsingError  parse_input_3(ParsedData& result, Input input);
  ```
- It's a discriminated union of types `T` and `E` with some convenience methods.

#### "How is it better than just an `std::variant<T,E>`?"

It behaves somewhat like `std::optional<T>`, giving focus to the expected, rather than the unexpected, case:

- `result.has_value()` - true if we got a value rather than an error.
- `if (result)` - checks for the same thing
- `*result` - gives us the `T` value if it exists, undefined behavior otherwise (same as `std::optional`, although many don't like this).
- `result.value()`, gives us the `T` value if it exists, or throws otherwise.

Actually, that last mode of access behaves differently than `std::optional` if we got an error: What it throws is a `bad_expected_access<E>`, with the returned error. This behavior can be thought of as a way to switch from expected-based to exception-based error-handling.

#### "Hey, I looked for it in the standard and it isn't there!"

`std::expected` will be part of the upcoming C++23 standard. The [proposal (P0323)](https://wg21.link/p0323) has recently been accepted.

This being said - it is quite usable already, since it requires no new language facilities:

- I can recommend one Sy Brand (tartanllama)'s [implementation](https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected), which can be used with C++11 or later. It also has some neat functional-style extensions (which may not be standardized).
- @Malachi recommends [estd::expected](https://github.com/malachi-iot/estdlib), part of a standard library implementation intended for embedded environments.

Comment: I really don't get why `*result` does not check for a valid value while `result.value()` does. Maybe they want you to use them the way you use a "raw pointer" that might be nullptr. Or, maybe they are worried with efficiency. I do not find that use the same way as you use a "raw pointer" is something good... we want to get rid of them, don't we? If the problem is efficiency, the roles could just be swapped. If you area lazy person and don't want to check, just use `*result` and wait for the throw. If you are concerned, you can use `result.value()`.

Comment: @AndréCaldas: Well, we need both a way to access the value with a check, and a way to access it without a check - for reasons of both expressivity and performance/avoiding overhead.

Comment: Yes! We agree on that. It is just that `*result` should be the way that throws. People say that we should have less "undefined behaviour". Those really worried about performance should be the ones that do not use `*result` they should use some `result.get_with_no_check()`. This would be much less error prone.

Comment: @AndréCaldas: Well, you have an argument with the standards committee. They decided it will be the other way around. I happen to think their choice is intuitive via the analogy to a pointer (i.e. dereferencing without a null check may cause undefined behavior), but your suggestion is not without merit.