# alternative to std::optional that can report failure reasons

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there an alternative to `std::optional` where I don't have to pass the `result` as a parameter to the function. I want the function to not modify its arguments (to be more pure/immutable).

TL;DR

The problem with `std::optional` seems to be that we lose information about errors. The function returns a value or something empty, so you cannot tell what went wrong.

**using std::optional**

```
std::optional<std::string> doSomething() {
    std::string value;
    int rc = callApi(value);

    if (rc == 0) {
        //do some processing on value
        return value;
    }

    return std::nullopt;
}

//calling the function seems much more pure/cleaner than when passing a result parameter.
```

**without std::optional**

```
int doSomething(std::string& result) {
    std::string value;
    int rc = callApi(value);

    if (rc == 0) { //if no error
        //do some processing on value and set result = value
        result = value;
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: If you want to return 2 or more things, then return a `pair` or `tuple` of those things.  The standard library does this with `std::unordered_map::insert` for instance.

Comment: You could use a `pair<int,string>` returning an error code and the result (or nothing).

Comment: Do you really need to return the error code from the underlying API? Wouldn't be better to throw an exception in case of error?

Comment: Thank you!
In c++ (modern cpp if you will), is it recommended to use `std::variant`/`std::pairt`/etc or to pass the `result` as a parameter.
Or is it just personal preference?

Comment: My opinion is to use `std::pair`.  There are already algorithm functions that work this way, for example `std::map::insert()`.

Comment: `variant` lets you return 1 value of N different types.  `pair`/`tuple` lets you return 2/N different values of 1 or more types

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go with `std::pair`

Comment: It sounds like you are putting prettiness over code simplicity.

Comment: what would be the simple solution? passing `result` as parameter to the function?

Comment: It just doesn't feel natural to return an `int` from every function because we need to account for the rc_code.

So I'm thinking of something like `std::pair<int, std::optional<std::string>>`

Answer (score 4):

It seems like what you're looking for is `std::expected`.

... it's not actually in the standard already, but:

- You can read a recent version of the proposal, [P0323 revision 10](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0323r10.html)
- You can use it! Or rather, [an implemented of it](https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected) by the talented Sy Brand / TartanLlama, including some nice extensions which I won't go into.

But - what is it?

Well... in a nutshell: When you want to return either some value, or some kind of failure/error descriptor, you just template those, say into T, E, and those are the template parameters: `std::expected<T, E>`. And since T and E are disjoint types, you know which of them you got back from the function.

Here's your function, adapted for an error type your API seems to have:

```
namespace my_api {
using error_t = int;
enum : error_t { success = 0, invalid_input = 1, /* etc. */ };
} // namespace my_api

std::expected<std::string, my_api::error_t> doSomething() {
    std::string value;
    my_api::error_t rc = callApi(value);
    if (rc != success) { return rc; }

    //do some processing on value
    return value;
}
```

Of course the `my_api` namespace is not part of my suggestion, it's merely an illustration, since you did not indicate how you would like to communicate errors. Actually, you might even add:

```
namespace my_api {
template <typename T>
using expected = std::expected<T, error_t>;
} // namespace my_api
```

and then your function signature becomes:

```
my_api::expected<std::string> doSomething();
```

---

See also: [What is std::expected in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68368581/1593077)

Comment: Should probably note that this is insanily overkill (as long as it's not standardized) for anything in which the pattern in question doesn't pervade the entire codebase.

Comment: I like this - but would prefer `std::pair` as it is in the current standard.

Comment: @raneshu: A pair of what?

Comment: `std::pair<rc_code, std::optional<result>> result_pair;`

Comment: Ah, pair _and_ optional. Yes, that will work quite well and is basically "poor man's `std::expected`". But you would probably need to write a long file of helper functions to work with these, as otherwise your readers would be rather confused.

Answer (score 1):

`std::variant` is a type-safe union that allows you to return one of a fixed set of types. In this case you'd want a `std::variant<std::string, int>`

**Using `std::variant`**

```cpp
std::variant<std::string, int>doSomething(){
    std::string value;
    int rc = callApi(value);

    if(rc == 0){ //if no error
       //do some processing on value
       return value;
    }

    return rc;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::optional` is not intended to return an error. It is a tool for a very simple concept of "having a value or not". From cppreference:

> Any instance of optional at any given point in time either contains a value or does not contain a value.

If you are writing a C++ function and an error is not a part of your business logic (i.e. you are not going to proceed when you receive an error instead of a usable result), just throw an exception. `std::runtime_error` will suit you fine. Or you can use `std::error_code`.

- Throwing an exception is perfectly fine performance-wise if the error rarelly occurrs.
- Throwing an exception simplifies your procedure logic. Instaed of checking each result for an error code you catch one exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'll present three options, though I'm sure somebody will come up with a more clever approach. In short: you could throw an error, you could return an instance of a custom struct or class, or you could use a std::variant.

**Option 1: Throw an Error**

Here, you can throw the error value (i.e. the return code from `callApi`) on failure, then wrap any calls to `doSomething()` in a `try ... catch` block.

```
std::string doSomething(){
  std::string value;
  int rc = callApi(value);

  if(rc) throw rc;

  //do some processing on value
  return value;
}
```

**Option 2: Return a Struct**

Here, you create a struct that holds both a `std::string` and a return code; this allows the encoding of both error information and a successfully-returned string.

```
struct ReturnString {
  std::string value;
  int rc;
}

ReturnString doSomething(){

  ReturnString return_value;
  std::string & value = return_value.value;
  int & rc = return_value.rc;

  rc = callApi(value);

  if(rc) return return_value;

  //do some processing on value
  return return_value;
}
```

Then, calling code can check the value of `rc`, process the error appropriately if nonzero, or use the string if 0.

You could even get fancy and use a generic struct, with the type of value being a template parameter. You could additionally add helper functions that check the value of `rc` to give you the string contents if appropriate. Rather than doing all that, though, you can use something similar that already exists in the standard library:

**Option 3: Use a Variant**

The `std::variant` represents a type-safe union, and thus can hold either a return code or a string. Helper functions can be used to determine which one it holds. So, you might do something like:

```
std::variant<int, std::string> doSomething(){
  std::variant<int, std::string> return_value;

  std::string value;
  int rc = callApi(value);

  if(rc) return rc;

  //do some processing on value
  return return_value;
}
```

Then, from your calling function, you can check the variant to see which type it holds, and proceed accordingly:

```
auto v = doSomething();
int rc;
if(std::holds_alternative<int>(v)) {
  rc = std::get<int>(v);
  //Process error accordingly
if(std::holds_alternative<std::string>(v)) {
  std::cout << "String returned was " << std::get<std::string>(v) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
re: option 1 - is it ok to simply throw int `rc` and not an actual `Error` or `Exception`?

Comment: Yes; in C++ you can throw any type that is not (1) incomplete or (2) an rvalue reference. In this case, since you're throwing an int, you catch it with `catch (const int & e)`. You could, of course, throw an error or other exception with the `what` attribute set as the value of rc, but this would require casting rc to a string, then presumably back to an integer to handle it.